# Updating Jsonb column in golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to update a Jsonb column value for a particular row.
I ran the query

```
UPDATE instruction.file SET "details" = (jsonb_set("details",'{"UploadBy"}','"test@test.com"'::jsonb, true)) WHERE id=820;
```

this works fine in the pgAdmin3.

When I tried to do the same in my Go code. Iam getting the error:"pq: invalid input syntax for type json"

My Go code:

```
func main() {
    uname := "test@test.com"

    err := Init() //Db init
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
        return
    }

    result, err1 := Db.Exec("UPDATE instruction.file SET \"details\" = (jsonb_set(\"details\",'{\"UploadBy\"}',$1::jsonb, true)) WHERE id=$2", uname, "820")
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err1)
        return
    }
    n, err1 := result.RowsAffected()
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err1)
        return
    }

    if n != 1 {
        err1 = errors.New("Unable to update instruction.file")
        fmt.Println("Error", err1)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Success")
    return
}
```

Comment: `Db.Exec('UPDATE instruction.file SET "details" = (jsonb_set("details",'{"UploadBy"}',$1::jsonb, true)) WHERE id=$2', uname, "820")` you tried of course and the error is the same?..

Comment: yes. Iam getting the same error (invalid input syntax for type json). Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: not really... seems go wants to convert smth to json?..

Comment: Just a tip: string literals containing quotes are best delimited by backticks (`\``). It avoids common syntax errors and at the very least makes your code easier to read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`to_jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
Db.Exec(`
    UPDATE instruction.file
    SET details = jsonb_set("details", '{"UploadBy"}', to_jsonb($1::text), true)
    WHERE id = $2
    `, uname, "820"
)
```

Comment: you sir, are a godsend!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the error:

"uname" was of the type string, when created like:

```
uname := "test@test.com"
```

It should be a json variable. Must be created like:

```
uname := `"test@test.com"`
```

I don't know whether it is the right answer. But it works.